# Access violation exception while trying to redirect std::cerr to file

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, cout

I'd like to redirect the output of `std::cerr` and `std::cout` to files. For this purpose, I have used the `rdbuf` functions as in the code sample below. Unfortunately, I receive the exception

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.

*(__imp_std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(...)) was 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

whenever I try to write anything to `std::cout` or `std::cerr`.

Here is a code sample that produces my problem:

```
void redirect()
{
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.log");
    auto cerrFileName = "cerr-" + oss.str();
    auto coutFileName = "cout-" + oss.str();


    std::ofstream cerrFile(cerrFileName, std::ios::ate); // file is created 
    std::cerr.rdbuf(cerrFile.rdbuf());

    std::ofstream coutFile(coutFileName, std::ios::ate); // file is created
    std::cout.rdbuf(coutFile.rdbuf());
}

int main()
{
    redirect();

    std::cout << "Test"; // The exception is thrown here.

    return 0;
}
```

This sample creates two files as it should but does not write anything into neither of them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider the lifetimes of the objects you're redirecting the output to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ofstream` own its buffer and when `std::ofstream` objects go out of scope they destroy the buffers, resulting in `std::cout` and `std::cerr` using invalid pointers to the buffers.

Make sure that the buffers do not get deleted prematurely.

Comment: Rookie mistake. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MxNx Mistakes are the only path to expertise!

Answer (score 2):

With e.g.

```
std::cout.rdbuf(coutFile.rdbuf());
```

you make `std::cout` *share* the same buffer as `coutFile`, you only set the *pointer*.

Unfortunately [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) is not reference counted. That means when the `redirect` function returns then `coutFile` is destructed and closed which include destructing the buffer object.

That leaves e.g. `std::cout` with a stray pointer to a non-existing buffer object.

The streams you share the buffer objects with needs to have a lifetime over the full program. *And* before you exit the program you need to restore the original buffers for `std::cout` and `std::cerr` ([`rdbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) returns pointers to the old buffers).

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you for your informative response.